How to right align a div element
I am trying to place a hamburger menu on the right of my page.

I just managed to put it on the same line as the header but there is no desired gap between the elements.

What I did:
margin-left:auto;    
margin-right:0px;

does not do anything. If I float the element right it jumps to the next line whereas I want the two elements on the same line
    #drop_menu{
        display:inline-block;
        float: right;
    }


Here is the full code:
I also tried:
#title_and_menu{
    position:relative;
    }

#drop_menu{
    display:inline-block;
    right: 200px;
    /*float: right;*/
}



#drop_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: right;*/
}

#hamburger_menu {
  width: 35px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#myHeader {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#myHeader:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-botttom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
<div id="title_and_menu">
  <div id="myHeader">
    <h1>9.</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="drop_menu">
    <div id="hamburger_menu"></div>
    <div id="hamburger_menu"></div>
    <div id="hamburger_menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="home_image.jpg" alt="home image">



Adding the following code:
#title_and_menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

Makes the top bar of the hamburger menu twice as thick as the two bottom ones:
temporal solution

Note that having multiple identical id attributes is not allowed.

This question is similar to: Controlling the amount of space in justify-content: space-between. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What do you mean "having multiple identical id attributes is not allowed" as in which ones are not allowed? If you could please state the names of the ids it would be great

What is meant is that your markup as posted is invalid as the id MUST be unique on the entire document ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Every ID in a document must be unique. No ID can be repeated. In your code the hamburger_menu ID is repeated, which is invalid.

You can use flexbox on #title_and_menu, with justify-content: space-between; for the left/right distribution and align-items: center; for the vertical centering of both:


#drop_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: right;*/
}

.hamburger_menu {
  width: 35px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#myHeader {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#myHeader:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#title_and_menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
<div id="title_and_menu">
  <div id="myHeader">
    <h1>9.</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="drop_menu">
    <div class="hamburger_menu"></div>
    <div class="hamburger_menu"></div>
    <div class="hamburger_menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="home_image.jpg" alt="home image">




I tried your solution but the hamburger menu is messed up when I do that. As in the top bar is thicker than the bottom 2 bars. I will post a picture in the question.

As you can see, it works in my snippet which contains all the code you provided. So there has to be some additional code which causes that and which you didn't post.

Consider fixing the duplicate ids here.

@MarkSchultheiss Done – I didn't want to change any original code (just add that one CSS rule), but of course duplicate IDs ("#hamburger_menu") are invalid HTML, so I changed those  to a class with the same name.

Above solution might actually solve the issue, but if you like to try positioning, you may use position: absolute; to the hamburger menu, you can place it on the right side of the page while keeping the header aligned to the left.


#title_and_menu {
  position: relative;
}

#myHeader {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 25px;
}

#drop_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger_menu {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#myHeader:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding: 25px;
}
<div id="title_and_menu">
  <div id="myHeader">
    <h1>9.</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="drop_menu">
    <div class="hamburger_menu"></div>
    <div class="hamburger_menu"></div>
    <div class="hamburger_menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<img src="home_image.jpg" alt="home image">




For additional information, you might use position documentation to understand how positioning works.

Consider fixing the duplicate ids here.

@MarkSchultheiss correct, completely forgot about it. Fixed the code. Thanks for noting.

@NijatMursali Just a heads up for future reference—the order of answers on a page is not fixed. So it's best to link to another answer instead of saying "Above solution..." etc.—since it might actually be below for some users.

Thank you, @Sean. Will be taking that into account for future answers.

You appear to what what is commonly called a "pancake stack" with header/body/footer - or maybe no footer but I included one to illustrate.
Lots of ugly excess CSS to make the visual more apparent here.
Fixed the duplicate ID issue by making them all classes and used those in the CSS.
padding-botttom: 25px; was mis-spelled but used a more modern em approach where I make the font size 16px which is the default for most browsers anyway.


body,
* {
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  padding: 1.5m;
}

.page-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  border: 1px #00ff0044 solid;
}

.header-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 2em;
  background-color: #00bedf44;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: solid 1px #0000ff;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.content-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid 1px #ffdd00;
  background-color: #ffdd0011;
}

.footer-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border: solid 1px #ffdd00;
  background-color: #ff000033;
  width: 100vw;
}

.my-header>* {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.my-header {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 1em;
  height: 2.5em;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.my-header:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.drop-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 3em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ff00df44;
  border: dashed 1px #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2em;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  width: 1em;
  background-color: black;
  height: 0.15em;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.home-logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid red 1px;
}
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="header-container title-and-menu">
    <div class="my-header">
      <h1>9.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-menu">
      <div class="hamburger-menu"></div>
      <div class="hamburger-menu"></div>
      <div class="hamburger-menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <h2>Introduction to introductions</h2>
    <img class="home-logo" src="home_image.jpg" alt="home image">
    <div>I have some cool content we all agreee!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div>footer I am</div>
    <img class="home-logo" src="home_image.jpg" alt="home image">
  </div>
</div>




This answer could be improved by removing all of the extra code and explanation that is not related to the core question, which is about the placement of the menu icon.
